# Base and thumbnail image etc not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, product-images, media

We list through a 3rd party Order Management system and have done for years but recently even after we select the Base image for the product it does not update in Magento Back-End.

I have to go into Magento to select any base image for it to show the image I chose in the Order management system.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Does anyone know of a script that would find any product that does not have an image assigned and select a random image as Base, small and thumbnail image?

Thanks

Comment: What extension are you using? If it's a paid extension, I suggest you contact the developer directly as it is unlikely that someone will have the answer here.

Comment: I am speaking to them at the moment but I was thinking of a manual fix for now as we list dozens of products daily and the listing department does not have access to Magento.